# Using perl to execute commands from csv file

Tags: perl, csv, cisco

What I am trying to do is is have my script read a csv file, or a text file (which ever is easiest), grab the hostname from cell A1, login to that device, then read A2, which would be an interface (ex:fa0/1), switch into the interface, then read cell A3, and change the description of the interface to what cell A3 says.  Log out, and repeat process for cell B1 etc...

The devices I am logging into are cisco routers/switches. What has me tripped up is how I put cisco IOS commands into my script, or do I just build out the commands and have the script essentially "paste" the command in IOS.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: may be a bash script is what you need instead of perl

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your "login to that device" command is here, but `split` is what you want in perl.

```
open CSV, '<'.'filename.txt' or die $!;
while (<CSV>) {
    my ($host, $interface, $new_description) = split ',', $_;
    # shell to host, do whatever with $interface to $new_description
}
```

It would help if you gave more detail, like what your commends look like – are they likely to span multiple lines? Also, you can probably do this with `awk` just as easily, if not more easily (and also with cut in the shell…).